# Proper Way to Call Multiple Mutations in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following setup for an action:

```
    myAction: ({commit}) => {
    commit('mutation1');
    commit('mutation2');
    commit('mutation3');
},
```

The thing is, I need `mutation1` to for sure run first (which it does most of the time) and I need `mutation2` to only run if `mutation1` succeeds, and so on for `mutation3`. Since calling a mutation won't return anything, I'm figuring there has to be a better way to do what I'm trying to do. Is there a best practice for calling multiple mutations that depend on the previous mutation to succeed?

Comment: How do you determine whether each mutation succeeds or not?

Comment: I guess that's my question. I have some internal rules determining success or failure (the mutations do some ajax calls within which can succeed or fail and return their own result to that effect) but the mutation itself doesn't indicate success or failure.

Comment: [Mutations must be synchronous](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html). If you need to do asynchronous work, you need to do it in an action. You can split your action into multiple actions and perform dependent changes by [composing your actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html).

Comment: As I typed my last comment, I came to that conclusion. This makes the most sense and my mutations were doing a bit too much. The mutations should probably be a reaction to the ajax, not call the ajax themselves.